# Only show content if current page is NOT one of 2 page templates

Tags: page-template, conditional-tags

I've been using this `if` conditional statement to only show content if the current page is NOT using a certain page template;

```
if (! is_page_template('template-custom.php')) {
    <!-- show some content  -->
}
```

which has been working fine. Only now I need to amend the statement to show content if the current page is NOT using one of 2 templates (So if the current page uses `template-custom.php` or `template-custom2.php` do NOT show the content).

I tried this;

```
if (! is_page_template('template-custom.php') || is_page_template('template-custom2.php')) {
    <!-- show some content  -->
}
```

and this;

```
if (! is_page_template('template-custom.php') || ! is_page_template('template-custom2.php')) {
    <!-- show some content  -->
}
```

but to no avil.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is pure PHP as per answer, you need `&&` (and) not `||` (or).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want don't want to show content if the current template is `template-custom.php` or `template-custom2.php` you can use:

```
if (!is_page_template('template-custom.php') && !is_page_template('template-custom2.php')) {
    <!-- show some content when you AREN NOT in template-custom.php NOR template-custom2.php -->
}
```

or

```
if (is_page_template('template-custom.php') || is_page_template('template-custom2.php')) {
    <!-- show some content when you ARE in template-custom.php OR template-custom2.php -->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if (! is_page_template('template-custom.php') || ! is_page_template('template-custom2.php')) {
    <!-- show some content  -->
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Nothing